# Eclipse - Running programs not in the native eclipse console

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently writing some ncurses code and the native Eclipse (3.2.2) console can't display its graphics. I'd instead like to run the program through xterm. What I want is to be able to start xterm and run from there. I'd prefer to not get involved with any plugins or that jazz. Just something simple.

EDIT

So I have the answer and it was pretty simple... 
Run -> External Tools -> External Tools -> New Launch Config...
Then select location of your terminal emulator. /usr/bin/gnome-terminal in my case. 
after that set the appropriate arguments. "-e ~/ncurses/start" in my case. 
Then make sure you aren't allocating a console by unchecking that option in the "Common" tab.

Comment: Just completed my answer with the 'external tool launcher' option... before realizing you already did came up with the same answer ;)
Anyway, I keep my answer here for archive.

Answer (score 9):

[Annon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112316/annon) add to his question:

> its a pain to keep switching back and forth from eclipse and the terminal. I'm looking for a way to just hit something like"F5" and have it run my ncurses program in a new xterm terminal process

The simplest way to do that is to report the command line into an external tool configuration, and point eclipse to use a shell (like described in [this program](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console.html))

[image: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/eclipse/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console-03.gif]

In the argument, you will add the command line eclipse execute (command line which can be retrieved as mentioned in the second part of this answer below).
Of course, replace 'cmd.exe' by the shell of your choice, and try **not setting** the '`Allocate Console`' checkbox in the Common tab of that external launcher.

[image: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/eclipse/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console-04.gif]

---

To launch through a xterm, without eclipse involved (not what you are asking for, just keep here for archive)

You can launch your program through Eclipse (Run Configurations), and observe through a 'ps' command the exact Java command line used.
Or launch it in debug mode, and right click the task in Debug view and open Properties. It will show the command line, as [documented here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg13645.html).

Then launch that command line directly in your console (Eclipse being not involved at all at this point).

[image: http://www.aicas.com/jamaica/3.4/doc/html/debugger1.gif]

Comment: Thanks for answering but this wasn't exactly what I was looking for :) I don't have a problem compiling and running through xterm but its a pain to keep switching back and forth from eclipse and the terminal. I'm looking for a way to just hit something like"F5" and have it run my ncurses program in a new xterm terminal process.

Comment: "http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg13645.html" become invalid. Besides, the "Command Line" of debug task's Property is empty, any idea?