# Configuring launches in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm a long-time Visual Studio user just now switching over to Eclipse. It's really nice, but I have a couple questions:

1) Is it possible to launch my app from Eclipse into a new, real terminal instead if the built-in console view?

2) I'd also really like it to automatically switch the perspective back to C/C++ after the program I'm debugging terminates. I've looked all over for a solution and I realize one probably doesn't exist, but I'm hoping somebody might know of a plugin or something that achieves this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1), may be my old answer about "[Eclipse - Runing programs not in the native eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908488/eclipse-runing-programs-not-in-the-native-eclipse-console)" can help. ([this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=743131) might also help)

Regarding 2), I don't think this exist for Java.
Oddly enough, this [has been implemented for Php](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163689).

But all this depends also on your Eclipse version and distribution.
(JDT for Java? PDT for Php?, CDT for C/C++?; ...)

Comment: Thanks! Running it as an external tool works well. There was one problem that the terminal would exit as soon as the program finished, making it hard to read the output. Now I launch a shell script that executes the program and then does "read pause" so it won't close until I hit enter.