# Redirection of output stream

Tags: java, io

Just for the Curiosity,can we print the output from eclipse console to command prompt,like I know there is a set.out method,but don't  know hot to do it exactly.Is there a possible way ?

Using setOut method,to a different console and not to a file

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to use an external console instead of the built-in one?

Comment: Exactly,instead of eclipse console,the cmd prompt,like the default way we used to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse - Runing programs not in the native eclipse console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908488/eclipse-runing-programs-not-in-the-native-eclipse-console)

Comment: no I was thinking whether a Java program could be written for that?

Comment: That contradicts what you just said you wanted... you may wish to clarify your question with an example, as well as a description of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect eclipse console output to a file (like this : [How can we redirect a Java program console output to multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714053/how-can-we-redirect-eclipse-console-output-to-a-file)) and, in another console window, from outside eclipse, you can (linux/cygwin) do something like tail -f on this file.

Notice that this does not mean eclipse will listen to what you type in your external console window.

Comment: That's not necessary, you can directly configure Eclipse to use an alternate console instead of the built-in one.