# eclipse ncurses and xterm, unknown characters printed

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ncurses, xterm

I faced with `Error opening terminal: unknown.` with `ncurses` and Eclipse Luna.

So installed `xterm` and add `TERM=xterm` in Run/Debug Configurations > Environment.

Now, when I run following simple "Hello World" app, some strange characters printed in the Eclipse console:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();                 /* Start curses mode     */
    printw("Hello World !!!"); /* Print Hello World    */
    refresh();                 /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();                   /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();                  /* End curses mode    */

    return 1;
}
```

What are these characters? And how to remove them?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @n.m.: I thought it was clear enough. Added.

Comment: the most likely problem is that xterm is not the kind of terminal you need to be writing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These characters are what `initscr()` outputs to do its job.

A terminal knows not to show these characters and interpret them in a special way. Since the Eclipse console is not a terminal, it has not a faintest idea.

If you want your program to work in both terminals and non-terminals, you need to check whether your standard output is a terminal, and avoid using `ncurses`-specific functions if it is not. See `man isatty`.

If you only need your program to work in terminals, just don't use Eclipse console. See [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908488/eclipse-runing-programs-not-in-the-native-eclipse-console) for set-up instructions.